# Docker RUN multiple instance of a image with different parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to docker, so this may sound a bit basic question.

I have a VS.Net core2 console application that is able to take some commandline parameters and provide different services. so in a normal command prompt I can run something like

`c:>dotnet myapplication.dll 5000 .\mydb1.db 
 c:>dotnet myapplication.dll 5001 .\mydb2.db`

which creates 2 instance of this application listing on port `5000` & `5001`.

I want to now create one docker container for this application and want to run multiple instance of that image and have an ability to pass this parameter as a commandline to the `docker run` command. However I am unable to see how to configure this either in the `docker-compose.yml` or the `Dockerfile`

**DockerFile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# ignoring some of the code here
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapplication.dll"]
```

**docker-Compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  my.app:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}my/app
    ports:
     - 5000:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dir/Dockerfile
```

I am trying to avoid creating multiple image one per each combination of commandline arguments. so is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docker containers are started with an entrypoint and a command; when the container actually starts they are simply concatenated together.  If the ENTRYPOINT in the `Dockerfile` is structured like a single command then the CMD in the `Dockerfile` or `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` contains arguments to it.

This means you should be able to set up your `docker-compose.yml` as:

```
services:
  my.app1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}my/app
    ports:
     - 5000:80
    command: [80, db1.db]
  my.app2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}my/app
    ports:
     - 5001:80
    command: [80, db2.db]
```

(As a side note: if one of the options to the program is the port to listen on, this needs to match the second port in the `ports:` specification, and in my example I've chosen to have both listen on the "normal" HTTP port and remap it on the hosts using the `ports:` setting.  One container could reach the other, if it needed to, as `http://my.app2/` on the default HTTP port.)