# How to define multiple services with slightly different parameters in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to create a list of variables in `docker-compose.yml` file and create a service for each variable based on template?

E.g. `PARAMS=[name_a, name_b, name_c]`

Create 3 services:

```
FOR param IN PARAMS:
    my-service-{param}:
        build: my-image
        container_name: my-container-{param}
        environment:
            NAME: {param}
            SOME_OTHER: ...
```

This code does not work of course, but the functionality I believe is clear.

Comment: There's a similar question that may help, I feel: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52815090/3132718

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such functionality in `docker-compose`. Maximum you can do is to use environment variables in in combinations with the values.

Having said that, you can use a cli templating engine as `mustache-cli` and use it to generate the docker-compose.yml.

You can install mustache with

```
sudo gem install mustache
```

after installation you need to create a template file `docker-compose.mustache` and parameter file `parameters.yml` and combine them in the final file as in this example:

**parameters.yml**

```
ports:
  - 10
  - 20
  - 30
```

**docker-compose.mustache**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
{{#ports}}
  web{{.}}:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "50{{.}}:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
{{/ports}}
```

Afterwards combine them

```
~# mustache parameters.yml docker-compose.mustache

version: "3.9"
services:
  web10:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5010:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web20:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5020:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web30:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5030:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

You can find good tutorial on [mustache on this link](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/mustache/the-ultimate-mustache-tutorial/) which can help you with to convert your current `docker-compose.yml` to the template.